# How to retrieve Http session data in multiple Methods within a class

Tags: java, session, httprequest

I need to retrieve users profile from Http Session. Since I need the same profile in couple different methods within the class is there a way that all the method access the same session? So I dont have to put the http request multiple times.  Below is the example of session and methods.
In the below methods you will see im putting the http request in both methods since they are both in same class it would help if I dont create seprate sessions.

Http Request:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    EntRProfile profile = (EntRProfile) session.getAttribute("profile");
```

Sample methods:

```
private Integer getClaimCount(HttpServletRequest request, String searchCriteria) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    EntRProfile profile = (EntRProfile) session.getAttribute("profile");
    Integer claimsCount = claimTDAO.getCountOfClaimsWithCurrentStatusNot(profile, "INI", searchCriteria);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("claimsPaginationCount", claimsCount);

    return claimsCount;
}
```

2nd Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/claims_history", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getClaims(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "claimsSearch", required = false) String searchCriteria, boolean keepOffset) throws Exception {


    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    EntRProfile profile = (EntRProfile) session.getAttribute("profile");

    request.getSession().setAttribute("claimsList", claimsList);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("claimsSearchCriteria", searchCriteria);

    Integer count = claimTDAO.getCountOfClaimsWithCurrentStatusNot(profile, "INI");
    request.setAttribute("claimsHistoryCount", count);

    return "claims_history";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a private method in your controller:

```
private EntRProfile getProfile(HttpServletRequest request) {
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     EntRProfile profile = (EntRProfile) session.getAttribute("profile");
     return profile;
}
```

Then you can get the profile by calling:

```
EntRProfile profile = getProfile(request);
```